# Multiple UIPicker views not displaying or re-loading data

Tags: uipickerview, textfield

I have multiple textfields with a UIPicker view and a done button however the UIPicker views are not presenting themselves in the simulator nor reloading the data.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var RoomTypeTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var WindowTypeTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ShelterTypeTextField: UITextField!

// Room Type, Window Type and Shelter Variables

//Room Type

var RoomType = ["Bedroom", "Bathroom", "Sitting Room", "Hallway", "Dining Room", "Hallway", "Kitchen", "Conservatory"]

var picker : UIPickerView!

//Window Type

var WindowType = ["Single Galzed", "Double galzed"]

//Shelter Type

var ShelterType = ["Sheltered", "Average", "Exposed"]


//Done button for UIPickerView

var toolBar = UIToolbar()

var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: "doneUIPicker")

var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100))
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("updatePicker"), name: UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)

    func updatePicker (){

    self.picker.reloadAllComponents()
    }

    picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 75/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    RoomTypeTextField.inputView = picker
    WindowTypeTextField.inputView = picker
    ShelterTypeTextField.inputView = picker

    RoomTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    WindowTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    ShelterTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if RoomTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

            return RoomType.count

        } else if WindowTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

            return WindowType.count

        } else if ShelterTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

            return ShelterType.count
        }

        return 1
}

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if RoomTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

            return RoomType[row]

        } else if WindowTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

            return WindowType[row]

        } else if ShelterTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

            return ShelterType[row]
        }

        return ""
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if RoomTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

        var itemselected = RoomType[row]
        RoomTypeTextField.text = itemselected

    } else if WindowTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

        var itemselected = WindowType[row]
        WindowTypeTextField.text = itemselected

    } else if ShelterTypeTextField.isFirstResponder() {

        var itemselected = ShelterType[row]
        ShelterTypeTextField.text = itemselected
}

func doneUIPicker (){

    RoomTypeTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    WindowTypeTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    ShelterTypeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a code in -(Void) textfieldDidBeginEditing to reloadAllComponents.
I work in objective C so can't give you sample code. but this will definitely work.

heres the sample code in Objective C.May be it gives you an idea

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

    {
         [Picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
```